# how to get firefox address bar url for python (pywin32)

Tags: python, firefox, pywin32

i need grab to firefox address bar. how to get address bar url for python ? (i need second part other browsers chrome and safari grabbing address bar but firefox is urgently).

Thanks.

Comment: You may send Alt-D, Ctrl-C, and get from clipboard.

Comment: i make in like a internet content filter. and i need external program calling and checking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Chrome tab URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675506/get-chrome-tab-url-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to go thru all top windows, and see if title contains firefox or check window class of firefox using spy++, then go thru all child windows to find URL, as a starting point do something like this

```
import win32gui

def enumerationCallaback(hwnd, results):
    text = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    if text.find("Mozilla Firefox") >= 0:
        results.append((hwnd, text))

mywindows = []    
win32gui.EnumWindows(enumerationCallaback, mywindows)
for win, text in mywindows:
    print text

def recurseChildWindow(hwnd, results):
    win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, recurseChildWindow, results)
    print hwnd
    # try to get window class, text etc using SendMessage and see if it is what we want

mychildren = []
recurseChildWindow(mywindows[0][0], mychildren)
```

Also you can use this module to do most of such tasks
http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/winGuiAuto.py.html