# python code to retrieve url from mozilla

Tags: python, firefox, url

is it any possibilities to retrieve currently open url in Mozilla firefox using python

Comment: duplicae? if you are windows this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598404/how-to-get-firefox-address-bar-url-for-python-pywin32/2598682#2598682

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write an [extension in python](http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org/) and access the browser that way.